# CMD Command for "Git Bash Here"

Tags: windows, git, bash

In Windows I can run "Git Bash Here" in the current directory by opening right click menu.

I want to place gitbashhere.bat in default path for commands to have got easy access from standard cmd window.

The `sh.exe --login -i` command only opens git bash in sh.exe's directory instead of the current directory.

How do I check what command is bound to "Git Bash Here"?

Answer (score 22):

#### How do I check what command is bound to "Git Bash Here"?

1. Open the Registry Editor using `regedt32` or `regedit`.
2. Menu "Edit" > "Find" > "Find what" and enter "git_shell"
3. Examine the returned Registry entries.
4. One will be:

   ```
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git_shell\command
   ```

   With the value:

   ```
   "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe" /c "pushd "%1" && "C:\git_install_dir\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"
   ```

   where `git_install_dir` is the directory where you have installed `git`.

   You can see it runs something similar to the following command:

   ```
   pushd "%1" && "C:\git_install_dir\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
   ```

Comment: I lost 3 hours to find a solution to remove from the context menu, the "Git bash here" and "Git GUI here" entries of a previous installation. No matter what i tried (ccleaner, install/unistall git, unregister dll, and other crap solution from the web) the the context menu keep showing the entries, pointing to the older installation folder. This solution helped me to find the two crap registry enties that was getting me crazy... thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

Another way to see how a specific program was started is to launch [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), look for the process in the list of processes (for git this would be "git-bash.exe") and double-click on the process to open the properties.

On the *'Image'* tab there's a text field that yields the command line of the process:

[image]

Comment: I couldn't get that properties window open but I can see the correct way to pass the path to git bash. I tried it in many ways and none of them worked for me but this one did. I use Vbscript to open folders and applications but with git bash I couldn't. I use this command and triple quotes for spaces.

Dim objShell
Dim strPath 
Dim explorer
Dim app

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 
explorer = "explorer.exe /e,"

app = """C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe""" & """--cd=C:\Users\gonen\Desktop\Sistema"""
objShell.Run app 

Set objShell = Nothing
WScript.Quit

Answer (score -4):

That is a windows shell thing. It depends on the git GUI toolkit that you've installed. For tortoiseGit, there's a setting hidden somewhere in the configuration menu. If that doesn't suit you: It's free and open software, so fix that :)